# Passing data from parent to child work 1 times

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have 3 components:

Main Comp

- Post Comp
- Author Comp

I passing data from `post comp` to `main comp`

```
this.$emit('author', this.author);
```

In `main comp` I passing data received from `post comp` to `author comp`

```
<router-view @author="author= $event"></router-view>
<router-view name="author" v-bind:author="author"></router-view>
```

It should work like charm, but just one time.

When I click button to passing data from `post comp` to `main comp` again, it's working (check by alert) but the `main comp` not passing new data to `author comp` althought I was using `watch` in `author comp`

```
watch: {
    author: function(){
        alert('OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment. can you put together a code pen of your problem? I tried to recreate your problem locally and could not. the prop updated the author string i was passing in perfectly. I suspect that something else in your app is causing reactivity problems.

Comment: The prop updated the author string perfectly but just 1 time, when I click again on post button, It's not passing data to author. I'll try to put project to code pen